# Calculation with rand operator concern

Tags: random, modulus

So, I am using the modulus and a rand as part of a function I am writing. Now, I understand that:

`rand() % 6 + 1;` gives me a random number between one and six in this situation. However, I also know that

`rand();` gives me a random value from 0 - 32767 and `srand;` changes the sequence

but I thought...

`%` = Whatever the remainder of `a` is after `a / b`.

... So,  if you were to break `rand() % 6 + 1;` up, what would it look like?

I need to make sense of this for my own good because I look at `rand() % 6 + 1;` like this:

some random number / 6 = remainder left over from the random. Then add the one.

So, my question is two fold:

1 - how does `rand()` get restricted to just 1 - 5 all of a sudden instead of the spectrum of numbers from 0 - 32767?

2 - Any of those numbers (1-5) divided by 6 gives you a fractional number, not a whole one and I thought modulus only works with whole numbers. What info am I missing here?

As you can see I am confused about this. Help is always appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rand()%6` gives the reminder of the random number generated when divided by 6

For example if `rand()` generates a number 100, then the result of 100%6 is the reminder obtained when 100 is divided by 6, which is 4. So whatever the number is generated from the function rand(), when %6 is done, the output will be within 0-5(the reminder when divided by 6).

"how does rand() get restricted to just 1 - 5 all of a sudden instead of the spectrum of numbers from 0 - 32767?"

rand() does not get restricted to "0-5", it still outputs the numbers from 0 - 32767(or whatever don't know the max limit). But when we do rand()%6, then the output will be in the range 0-5

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was just curious how it would play out if the random number was 1. Since 1/6 = 0.16 what happens then?

Comment: if rand() generates 1, then 1%6 is 1. Because if u divide 1 by 6 you will get 0 as the quotient and 1 as the reminder.